# Does jQuery have a hashtable type mutable data structure?

Tags: jquery, data-structures

Pseudo-code is probably the best way to show what I'm looking to do in jQuery:

```
$(selector).each(function() {
    // pull data from LI tags or whatever, store in variables (imgURL, tagline, summary)
    $someDataStructure.add({imgURL, tagline, summary});
});
```

Then later... reference the structure

```
 $someDataStructure.each(function() {
     var x = $someDataStructure['imgURL'];
     // etc.
 });
```

Any suggestions on how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery is just JavaScript, and JavaScript has objects. You can use JS Objects similarly to a C++ map or C# Dictionary. For example, you can create an array of objects and have indices that you can name:

```
var liTags = [];

$(selector).each(function() {
   // pull data from LI tags or whatever
   //store in variables (imgURL, tagline, summary)
   liTags.push({'imgURL': imgURL, 'tagline': tagline, 'summary': summary});
});
```

Then later:

```
for(int i = 0; i < liTags.length; ++i) {
   var imgURL = liTags[i]['imgURL']; //or liTags[i].imgURL;
}
```

Comment: @Chad Technically, this is just JavaScript associative arrays, not JSON, right? :)

Comment: Technically speaking, JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a standalone format that's _derived from_ (and is almost identical to) Javascript's native object declaration syntax.

Comment: Oh, and actually it's called an object. "Associative array" is a colloquialism based on comparisons with some other languages.

Comment: well actually json would be `"imgURL": "somestring"`; you MUST use double quotes and you CANNOT put a variable in JSON - it's static

Comment: **Edit:** Changed original post to hopefully be more semantically correct

Answer (score 1):

You can actually attach data to a jquery element using the [data api](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

So do something in the lines of:

```
$(selector).each(function() {
    /* I suppose here you have three available variables named:
       imgURL, tagline, summary
        that you got from the element itself or from somewhere else
     */
    $(this).data({imgURL: imgURL, tagline: tagline, summary:summary })
    /* you could also write it {'imgURL': imgURL, etc. } if it looks clearer: the first is the hashtable key, the second a variable containing the value */
}
```

and then just retrieve it from each jquery element!

```
$(selector).data()
```

or

```
$(selector).data('imgURL')
```

That's for attaching an 'hashtable' to an element.

In javascript you have 'associative arrays' (hashtables).

You can write them as:
`myarray = {key:'value'}`

and you can access them as:

`myarray['attribute']` or `myarray.attribute` as you prefer

PS. please note that I did not test the code up there, it might require some minor tweaks

Comment: $.data() is cool, but I don't see any way to kind of "push" objects into it. I am looping through a bunch of DIVs and pulling data out, I'd need some way to keep adding things to a list/array.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack : `{imgURL, tagline, summary}` is pseudo code I guess? please check my edit and let me know if that's what you mean...

Comment: Oh I see, you're attaching the data to each element in the loop, so that's sort of pushing onto a stack in a sense. Got it. Hmm.. unfortunately it still doesn't quite work for what I need, because I could very well be destroying the selectors once I've gathered data from them. I'm not sure $.data() is what I really need in this case.